# Return Unique Object by Most Recent Date Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have this array:

```
[
   {listName: "list1", hit: false, date: "2022-10-19"},
   {listName: "list1", hit: false, date: "2021-07-05"},
   {listName: "list2", hit: true, date: "2022-05-10"},
   {listName: "list2", hit: true, date: "2022-09-05"}
]
```

I want to return the unique elements listName and hit by most recent date.  So this:

```
[
   {listName: "list1", hit: false, date: "2022-10-19"},
   {listName: "list2", hit: true, date: "2022-09-05"}
]
```

TIA

Comment: To clarify, it's most recent date for each unique list name?

Comment: Create an object whose keys are the list names. Loop through the array, replacing the value of a key if the date is newer. At the end, `Object.values(theObject)` will be the list you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing this, one of which is by combining Object.values, a reduce iterator which will track unique rows by combining the listName and hit state as a key - and then just comparing dates

```js
let data = [{
    listName: "list1",
    hit: false,
    date: "2022-10-19"
  },
  {
    listName: "list1",
    hit: false,
    date: "2021-07-05"
  },
  {
    listName: "list2",
    hit: true,
    date: "2022-05-10"
  },
  {
    listName: "list2",
    hit: true,
    date: "2022-09-05"
  }
]

let sorted = Object.values(data.reduce((b, a) => {
  let key = a.listName + a.hit;
  b[key] = b[key] ?? a
  if (new Date(b[key].date) < new Date(a.date)) b[key] = a;
  return b
}, {}))
console.log(sorted)
```